# How to fill consent screen values for mobile app?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

Since a few days, users of my **android mobile application** are getting a warning, because the app is using sensitive data.

My app requests the daily steps count from fitnessAPI to display it.

I have read that I should go through the verification process of the oauth screen.

But I do not really know what data I should put in it. It seems rather "web" oriented, because it asks me a application homepage link, and application privacy policy link.

I do not know what I should put in **these fields for a mobile app**.

Should I put a link to the google play store page of the application?
Or a link to my website that shows my work?

[image]

Comment: Your need to do exactly what it says you need links to your home page where all of these pages are hosted.   I have a video on how to prepare for verification  that might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lzIuNmNX9N8

Comment: Thank you for your answer and video, it helped. But there is no area to put a google play store link to the application, so they can test it?

Comment: You cant put the play store link. You need to register a domain and host these on your domain. a play store link does not qualify as the domain for your application.

Comment: Thank you. I am a wear os watch faces developer. I have like 50+ applications, associated to 2 different google cloud projects (like 30 on the first, and 20 on the second). My website is dedicated to my applications, but there are multiple applications referenced on it (http://themaapps.com/). The homepage of the website shows a few of my applications. How to be sure that google will certificate the associated domain ? Should I show only 2 of my applications on the homepage (like one of each project?)

Comment: I really think you need to have a site or page dedicated to each of your apps to clearly inform the users the intent of each of the apps.   But i am not google i suggest you try and go though the process google will give you direction if there are any issues

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a registered domain to host these files

[Preparing for verification](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#zippy=%2Csteps-to-prepare-for-verification)

[image]